# Using Ray Tune to tune number of hidden layers in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, hyperparameters, ray-tune

Is there any way to treat number of layers in a model as a hyperparameter in ray tune?
in THIS example, I want to add a set to `param_space` to tune number of hidden layers like any other hyperparameter. How can I do it?

```
import argparse
import os

from filelock import FileLock
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

import ray
from ray import air, tune
from ray.tune.schedulers import AsyncHyperBandScheduler
from ray.tune.integration.keras import TuneReportCallback


def train_mnist(config):
    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32159
    import tensorflow as tf

    batch_size = 128
    num_classes = 10
    epochs = 12

    with FileLock(os.path.expanduser("~/.data.lock")):
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(config["hidden"], activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )

    model.compile(
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=config["lr"], momentum=config["momentum"]),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )

    model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=0,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        callbacks=[TuneReportCallback({"mean_accuracy": "accuracy"})],
    )


def tune_mnist(num_training_iterations):
    sched = AsyncHyperBandScheduler(
        time_attr="training_iteration", max_t=400, grace_period=20
    )

    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        tune.with_resources(train_mnist, resources={"cpu": 2, "gpu": 0}),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            metric="mean_accuracy",
            mode="max",
            scheduler=sched,
            num_samples=10,
        ),
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="exp",
            stop={"mean_accuracy": 0.99, "training_iteration": num_training_iterations},
        ),
        param_space={
            "threads": 2,
            "lr": tune.uniform(0.001, 0.1),
            "momentum": tune.uniform(0.1, 0.9),
            "hidden": tune.randint(32, 512),
        },
    )
    results = tuner.fit()

    print("Best hyperparameters found were: ", results.get_best_result().config)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--smoke-test", action="store_true", help="Finish quickly for testing"
    )
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
    if args.smoke_test:
        ray.init(num_cpus=4)

    tune_mnist(num_training_iterations=5 if args.smoke_test else 300)
```

I've tried to read the documentation of Ray Tune but I didn't find any solution for this. If not possible using Ray Tune, are there any different libraries for this?